# Accessing permanent cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 7.1 app, I have implemented SSO, and now I'd like to add the option to redirect the user to the page he tried to access after authenticating. To do so, since the user leaves the application to complete the authentication process, I save the URL in a permanent cookie.

```
def authenticate_user
  return if Current.user
  
  cookies.permanent[:return_to] = request.url
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

And after confirming the user's identity

```
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to cookies.permanent[:return_to] || home_path
```

However, the user is always redirected to `home_path` even if the cookie is there

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies by default have "SameSite" value of "Lax". We can see from your screenshot that it is indeed the case for the cookie in question. This means that the cookie is passed along with the request if the user navigates to your site using a GET request. Or with any request that originates on your page. But with dangerous methods like POST, that come from elsewhere, the cookie is not passed.

You could change the cookie "SameSite" value to be "None" so that it is indeed sent.

```
cookies.permanent[:return_to] = { value: request.url, same_site: :none, secure: true }
```

Alternatively rather than redirect the user to their destination directly, after authentication redirect them to some in-between route. The request to there is a GET request and the cookie should be there for you (I think. Not 100% sure about this).

Alternatively, if you can modify the callback url, store the request url as a query parameter on the callback url.

Comment: For completeness' sake, instead of using `permanent` and keeping the cookie around for 20 years, The expiration could be set manually as `cookies[:return_to] = { value: request.url, expires: 5.minutes.from_now, same_site: :none, secure: true }`. This is the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies/ChainedCookieJars.html#method-i-permanent

> This jar is only meant for writing. You’ll read permanent cookies through the regular accessor.

```
redirect_to cookies[:return_to] || home_path
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I get the same behavior.

Comment: Is your authentication on the same domain as the main application?
Cookies are by default not passed cross-domain.

Comment: No, Microsoft handles the authentication, which redirects back to the application afterward. Write and read of the cookie happen on the same domain.

Comment: I suspect the issue is cookie SameSite policy. Is the request from Microsoft back to your application GET, POST or something else?

Comment: The request from Microsoft is a POST (from the log `Started POST "/saml/acs" for ...`).

Comment: Keeping this answer here as is, since that was indeed one of the issues. Added another answer to explain the SameSite situation.

Comment: With the `same_site: none`, `format.html { redirect_to cookies.permanent[:return_to] || home_path }` works fine.